# Continuation of $\sum \sigma_\nu(n) a(n) n^{-s}$ for $a(\cdot)$ coming from a half-integral weight form

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation, half-integral-weight

In some of my work, I've run into a wall trying to understand whether a Dirichlet series has a meromorphic continuation or not. Let $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a(n) e(nz)$ be a half-integral weight cuspidal Hecke eigenform on $\Gamma_0(4)$, and let $\sigma_\nu(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d^\nu$ be the divisor function.

> Do we know if the Dirichlet series
> $$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n) \sigma_\nu(n)}{n^s} \tag{1}$$
> can be continued to $\mathbb{C}$?

The analogue in the case when we replace $f$ by a *full integral weight* Hecke cuspform $g = \sum b(n) \sigma_\nu(n) n^{-s}$ is straightforward to understand. Comparing Euler products will show (ignoring bad primes) that
$$ \sum \frac{b(n) \sigma_\nu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{L(s, g) L(s - \nu, g)}{\zeta(2s - \nu)}.$$
In the half-integral weight case, we cannot compare Euler products as we don't have multiplicativity, but Euler products are the only way I know to broadly tackle identities like this.

I'm hoping that there are other techniques for getting the continuation of series like $(1)$, or alternatively that it's known how to determine if such a series even has meromorphic continuation at all.

Comment: This looks like the kind of Dirichlet series you could handle by a Rankin-Selberg integral of $f$ against a half-integral weight Eisenstein series against a weight $0$ level $1$ Eisenstein series.  Unfolding with the half-integral weight should give your desired series.  The meromorphic continuation is then inherited from that of the Eisenstein series.

Comment: Ah, of course. This is true, and yes indeed this series has meromorphic continuation. And I now realize I slightly over-distilled my question. And it might have a pole at $s = 3/4$ coming from the half-integral weight Eisenstein series. Thanks Matt.